# Template is missing in action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, missing-template

I wrote a "follow" method in UsersController

```
def start_following
    @user = current_user
    @user_to_follow = User.find(params[:id])
    unless @user_to_follow == @user
        @follow_link = @user.follow_link.create(:follow_you_id => @user_to_follow.id, :user_id => @user.id)
        @user.save
        flash[:start_following] = "You started following" + @user_to_follow.name 
    else
        flash[:cant_follow] = "You cannot follow yourself"
    end
end
```

Pretty simple. And In the view, I have

```
<%= link_to 'Follow', follow_user_path(@user) %>
```

In routes,

```
resources :users do
 member do
    get 'follow' => "users#start_following", :as => 'follow'
```

When I click on the link, it complains: `Missing template users/start_following`

So, how do I make it just stay on the same page after the action?
The view page that I want to stay on is Show view of the user is to be followed.
ex: users/{user_id}. Is simply redirecting not a solution? I thought adding `redirect_to {somewhere}` would get rid of the error, but it didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would redirect to the user in question. If you are using the standard resourceful routes then you can just do

```
redirect_to(@user_to_follow)
```

As an aside it's generally considered bad practice to have GET requests that make changes - people normally use put/patch/post/delete requests for those. You can fall afoul of browsers pre-fetching links without the user actually clicking on them.

Comment: Thank you for the side note. How do I make it a PUT request instead of GET?

Comment: Change your routes file to be a put rather then a get then either add :method => :put to your link_to (requires the rails javascript stuff) or make it a form (button_to can be a quick shortcut for that)

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
redirect_to :back, :notice => "successfully followed someone..."
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes `redirect_to` solves your problem, I suspect you forgot to add it to both branches of the `unless`

The code would look like this:

```
def start_following
    @user = current_user
    @user_to_follow = User.find(params[:id])
    unless @user_to_follow == @user
        @follow_link = @user.follow_link.create(:follow_you_id => @user_to_follow.id, :user_id => @user.id)
        @user.save
        flash[:start_following] = "You started following" + @user_to_follow.name 
    else
        flash[:cant_follow] = "You cannot follow yourself"
    end
    redirect_to @user_to_follow
end
```